# CPUs are overused with internet browsers, maybe Ubuntu+i5+JS don's work well

Tags: performance, intel, cpu, cpu-load, multi-core

I'm having trouble with the Ubuntu 14.04 on PCs Intel NUC i5 8 GB RAM SSD HD.

They are used mostly with Google Spreadhseets and are high usage of internet browsers and JS applications.

PCs are quite well resourced in CPU, RAM and HD but they are not working properly since occasionally there are **peaks of CPU usage** that freezes the computer. I think is for JS execution. Here you have a print screen of System Monitor:
[image]

- Any CPU firmware maybe missing?
- Are there any issues with JS execution or whatever in Ubuntu known?
- How can I fix this? Cannot be normal those peaks just for some browsing and G. Spreadsheet work.

Thanks in asvance!

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Have you compared the CPU usage values to i.e. Windows with the same browser and the same webpages?

Comment: What browser are you using? I think that the JavaScript interpreter is a part of the browser, not of the OS (I am not entirely sure, though). On the other hand, I have some issues with stuff from Google too, if I recall correctly. My browser is Pale Moon, what is yours?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your feedback, I use Chrome, but Firefox gets the same results, any other browser recommended?. No, I have not compared with a Windows install, I will do it but first I would like more feedback from the community.

Comment: @Dugi and MadMike, any further assistance? thanks

Comment: @EmilioNicolás If I were you, I'd try to open that document on some other computer that has a different OS.

Comment: The Intel NUC platform is a cost effective PC implementation that offers many of the features of a full size computer in a compact form. Despite all the fanfare about performance, the NUC is still a 2 core processor. It's very likely you are experiencing the hardware limitation of the NUC CPU. I tested your examples with SRWare Iron Version 50.0.2650.0 (a 64-bit Chromium derivative). My tests showed similar performance limitations executing the same apps (Google Docs, Sheets) on an Intel i5 3570k 4 core CPU.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnLittleton !! So, if you experienced same results in the tests you made, it's not NUC fault the low performance in the Sheets, right?

Comment: @Emilio Nicolas: Yes. That would be my conclusion. Two different hardware platforms using two different software platforms achieving similar results would imply the common denominator achieving a similar performance profile is "the Sheets".

Answer (score 0):

It is a very long standing and known problem of the website (Google Docs), that goes across browsers and OSs. [They know it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Ixj1FJ_JwFU), but form the look of it I'd say that they are not working on it.